# Getting Empty response when connecting SharePoint 2016 Excel Web Service method via SOAP client

Tags: excel, web-services, soap-client, sharepoint-2016

We have a SharePoint 2016 farm and we try to connect the site and Excel Service via SOAP client. When we use OpenWorkbook for getting session ID, its working fine and the session ID is coming. With that session if we call other methods like GetCell, GetRange, GetRangeA1, SetCell, SetRange, SetRangeA1 we are getting empty response. The same methods are working fine in SharePoint 2010 sites but for 2016 sites this issue is happening. Using Powershell commands (New-WebServiceProxy) also getting the same empty response error.

> PSMessageDetails : Exception : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "GetCell" with "6" argument(s): "Server was unable to process request. ---> The request failed with an empty response." ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> The request failed with an empty response. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1vti_bin_ex celservice_asmx_WSDL.ExcelService.GetCell(String sessionId, String sheetName, Int32 row, Int32 column, Boolean formatted, Status[]& status) at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , String , Int32 , Int32 , String , PSReference ) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame) TargetObject : CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException ErrorDetails : InvocationInfo : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo ScriptStackTrace : at , : line 1 PipelineIterationInfo : {}

Tried using the Powershell command New-WebServiceProxy to connect to the Excel Web Service and accessed methods. OpenWorkboook method is working fine but other methods like GetCell, GetRange, GetRangeA1, SetCell, SetRange, SetRangeA1 we are getting empty response. It should fetch the values from the connected Excel and give us the proper response but its giving empty response.